# assign_attributes without overwriting not nil data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there an equivalent to `assign_attributes` without attribute overwriting?

Let me explain with a quick exemple:

```ruby
my_model = MyModel.new(first_name: 'Romain', age: nil)

new_attributes = {first_name: 'Pierre', last_name: 'Roger', age: 27}
my_model.assign_attributes(new_attributes)
# What I get : <first_name='Pierre', last_name='Roger', age=27>
#  * Romain is overwritten by Pierre
#  * nil is overwritten by 27
# What I would like : <first_name='Romain', last_name='Roger', age=27>
#  * Romain isn't overwritten by Pierre
#  * nil is overwritten by 27
```

I know I could do something like this, but it doesn't seem right:

```ruby
new_attributes.merge(
    my_model.slice(:first_name, :last_name, :age)
            .select { |_, val| !val.nil? }
)
my_model.assign_attributes(new_attributes)
```

Any idea?

Comment: The main problem with that question is that nobody will risk saying that definitively there is no such a method. I am gona say: I have never seen such a method defined on ActiveRecord/ActiveModel and I woudl guess that there is not as it does not make much of the sense to have functionality like this in core rails.

Comment: Yes I do know that. I'm just hopping someone know a solution :)

Comment: No, rails doesn't provide any method to do that. A custom solution is advisable and i guess you already have one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment I don't think there is a ready to use method in ActiveRecord to do this. However, you can write your own, or even better - modify existing `assign_attributes` method. Naturally we need to be extra careful not to break it basic functionality - we'll only expand it a little bit.

`assign_attributes` method is defined in `ActiveRecord::AttributeAssignment` module, which is then included in `ActiveRecord::Base`. We could override it directly in its module, but it seems cleaner to wirte a new module instead and include it in `ActiveRecord::Base` instead (as we can call `super` then, instead of alias chaining). Copy the following code to a new file in `config/initializers` (any name would do):

```
module ActiveRecord::AttributeAssignmentOverride
  def assign_attributes(new_attributes, options={})
    return super(new_attributes) if options.fetch(:override, true)
    super(new_attributes.select {|k,_| self[k].nil? })
  end
end

class ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveRecord::AttributeAssignmentOverride
end
```

Then you can use `assign_attributes` the usual way (after restart naturally):

```
model.assign_attributes(new_params)
```

which will work as usual, overriding all the non-nil values. However, you can now add extra option:

```
 model.assign_attributes(new_params, override: false)
```

which will not touch already assigned values.

### Gotcha

The code above will only work in rails 4. Rails 3 uses `attr_accessible` instead of strong params for mass assignment security. Those could depends on many conditions, hence in rails 3 default `assign_attributes` method accepts two arguments (same as our new one). That means that you will also need to pass options to each call to super.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
my_model = MyModel.new(first_name: 'Romain', age: nil)
new_attributes = {first_name: 'Pierre', last_name: 'Roger', age: 27}

my_model.assign_attributes(my_model.attributes.reject{|k,v|v.nil?}.reverse_merge(new_attributes))
```

Comment: The algo should work but what I was wondering is : is their an existing method which does that directly?

Comment: The issue here is that you do *not* want to overwrite non-nil values, but all Rails/Ruby `merge` methods *do* overwrite them. I don't think there are existing methods that have that behavior.